# How to trigger inner class event handler inside an event handler (JAVA)

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jtextfield, keylistener

I have a JTextField with a KeyListener hanging on to it. Inside the keyPressed I check to see if the key being pressed is enter. After this I would like to call a different event handler inside an inner class (inner class only contains this handler).

This is what I have, but evidently: new handler() doesn't seem to launch the inner class handler.

Key eventhandler:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent k) {
    if(k.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
         new handler();
    }
}
```

Inner class eventhandler:

```
public class handler implements ActionListener{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    int red = Integer.parseInt(roodT.getText());
    int groen = Integer.parseInt(groenT.getText());
    int blauw = Integer.parseInt(blauwT.getText());
    if(red>255){
        red = 255;
    } else if (red < 0){
        red = 0;
    }
    if(groen>255){
        groen = 255;
    } else if (groen < 0){
        groen = 0;
    }
    if(blauw>255){
        blauw = 255;
    } else if (blauw < 0){
        blauw = 0;
    }
    inhoud.setBackground(new Color(red, groen, blauw));
}
```

}

This is my first time posting here so sorry if this question isn't formatted correctly.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is well formatted and+ well asked, +1 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a `JTextField` you can directly add your `handler` to it:

```
JTextField someField = new JTextField(20);
someField.addActionListener(new handler());
```

`ActionListener` is automatically triggered upon `ENTER`-pressed.

For all `JTextComponent`, instead of using `KeyListener`, use `DocumentListener` and `DocumentFilter`.

For other `JComponent` use [Swing KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

In all cases, stay away from `KeyListener` which is a low-level API.

Answer (score 2):

Just attach the `ActionListener` directly to the `JTextField`. It will be triggered when ENTER is pressed. This is build-in behavior of the `JTextField`.

For further reference:

- Do not attach a `KeyListener` to a `JTextComponent`. Use `DocumentListener` and/or `DocumentFilter`
- You should have used `(new handler()).actionPerformed( new ActionEvent( ... ) );` to make your code 'work'

Answer (score -2):

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent k) {
    if(k.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
         new handler().**actionPerformed(k)**;
    }
}
```

you forgot to call actionPerformed.

Comment: Not only your code does not even compile (`KeyEvent` cannot be casted to `ActionEvent)`, it is also a bad advice. Take a look at the other answers.